# Make round corners of Drawable object (app icons) programatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

This method returns the devices launcher icons and its possible to manipulate the drawables. But what I want is to make the drawables circular or possibly round the corners.

If its possible, could you show me how?

```
 private Drawable mIcon;

 public Drawable getIcon() {
    if (mIcon == null) {
        if (mApkFile.exists()) {

            mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());

            return mIcon;
        } else {
            mMounted = false;
        }
    } else if (!mMounted) {
        // If the app wasn't mounted but is now mounted, reload
        // its icon.
        if (mApkFile.exists()) {
            mMounted = true;
            mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
            return mIcon;
        }
    } else {
        return mIcon;
    }

    return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html). The process will look like this:

1. Draw the icon `mIcon` onto a `Bitmap` (create the `Bitmap` first, using the parameters of `mIcon`)
2. Use [RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html) to turn the `Bitmap` into a `RoundedBitmapDrawable`
3. Use `setCornerRadius(float cornerRadius)` on your new `RoundedBitmapDrawable` to give it the corners you wanted

At this point you should have a `RoundedBitmapDrawable` which will draw the icon, but with rounded corners, when `draw(Canvas canvas)` is called on it :-)

Comment: Always happy to help :-) If the answer ends up solving your problem, please remember to mark it as correct and maybe even upvoting it :-D Thanks! ^^